# Hibernate reactive + spring boot, exceptio "Unable to locate persister"

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-reactive

using

```
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, hibernateReactiveProperties());

        Mutiny.SessionFactory reactiveSessionFactory = emf.unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
```

but there are no entities being scan although they are marked with `@Entity` annotation.
I wonder if there should be a place to configure the package to scan for the `EntityManagerFactory`?

In Spring there is `LocalSessionFactoryBean` with its setter `setPackagesToScan("com.123.123")`

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding `class` tag for each entity in persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.reactive.provider.ReactivePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.company.EntityClassName</class>


    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```